# My keyboard types some letters twice

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, drivers, keyboard, control-panel

Why does my keyboard sometimes type letters twice when am typing for example i may mean to type ***dont*** but i get ***donnt*** (The "n" was typed twice).

This happenns on most of the keys.

Please Note that am using a brand New llapptop (laptop) - **DELL**
I recently upgraded from Windows 7 professional to Windows 10

Also Note tthat I went to the Keyboard settings under Control panel and adjusted the **Repeat rate** and **Repeat Delay** to the lowest value possible but that didn't help.

I have the **Integrated PS/2 Keyboard drivers** (I tried installing the **HID Keyboard Device driver** but I failed)[image: Device Manager screenshot]

I need help please bbecause this thing can be very annoying...

Comment: Attach USB keyboard! maybe it's hardware thing!

Comment: Try installing the latest BIOS for your laptop.